# Denary to binary conversion program

Tags: binary

How does this denary to binary program work?  I am finding it hard to comprehend what is happening behind the code.

Can someone explain the lines 6 onwards?

```
Number = int(input("Hello. \n\nPlease enter a number to convert: "))

if Number < 0:
    print ("Can't be less than 0")
else:
    Remainder = 0
    String = ""
    while Number > 0:
        Remainder = Number % 2
        Number = Number // 2
        String = str(Remainder) + String
    print (String)
```

Comment: Walk through it mentally. Pick a number and try it out by hand to see what it’s doing.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to separate out the last part of the binary number, stick it in a buffer, and then remove it from "Number". The method is general and can be used for other bases as well.

Start by looking at it as a dec -> dec "conversion" to understand the principle.

Let's say you have the number 174 (base10). If you want to parse out each individual piece (read as "digit") of it you can calculate the number modulo the base (10), then do an integer division to "remove" that digit from the number.  I.e. 174%10 and 174//10 => (Number) 17|4 (Reminder). Next iteration you have 17 from the division and when you perform the same procedure, it'll split it up into 1|7. On the next iteration you'll get 0|1, and after that "Number" will be 0 (which is the exit condition for the loop (while Number > 0)).

In each iteration of the loop you take the remainder (which will be a single digit for the specific base you use (it's a basic property of how bases work)), convert it to a string and concatenate it with the string you had from previous iterations (note the order in the code!), and you'll get the converted number once you've divided your way down to zero.

As mentioned before, this works for any base; you can use base 16 to convert to hex (though you'll need to do some translations for digits above 9), octal (base 8), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Python code for converting denary into binary

```
denary= int(input('Denary: '))
 binary= [0,0,0,0]
 while denary>0:
     for n,i in enumerate(binary):
         if denary//(2**(3-n))>=1:
             binary[n]= 1
             denary -= 2**(3-n)
             print(denary)
 print (binary)
```